# How to return all subsets of a list from a column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list `a = [A,B,C,D]`.

`Concatenated_values` is a column of lists in a `df`. How do I get all the subsets of list `a`, that exist in column `Concatenated_values`?

```
Concatenated_values 

[B,C]

[A,B,C,D] 

[B,C,D]

[P,Q,R,S,T]

[C,D]
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Can you add some more details?

Comment: Please provide us more detail about your problem statement and show your work.

Comment: If I take list named a which is  equal to [A,B,C,D] and try to find all it's subsets from the column in a df that I have shown, my output should be [B,C]  [A,,B,C,D] [B,C,D] and [C D]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert both `a` and the list entries to sets and use [`issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset) and boolean indexing:

```
set_a = set(a)
df[df.Concatenated_values.apply(lambda x: set(x).issubset(set_a))]
```

Result:

```
  Concatenated_values
0              [B, C]
1        [A, B, C, D]
2           [B, C, D]
4              [C, D]
```

Note: `issubset` accepts any iterable as an argument, so you could also use `set(x).issubset(a)`, but I find the explicit conversion of `a` to a set clearer and probably more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

> ```
> itertools.combinations(iterable, r)
> ```
>
> Return r length subsequences of elements from
>   the input iterable.
>
> Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the
>   input iterable is sorted, the
>   combination tuples will be produced in
>   sorted order.

You can concatenate all your lists into one and then get all combinations.